# C# null reference error

Tags: c#

Can't seem to find what's wrong here, I'm using this method :

```
public void AddPlayerToTeam(Player player, Team team)
{
    Team t = new Team();
    if(team.PlayersList.Count>=20)
        return;
    if (!(team.PlayersList.Contains(player)))
        team.PlayersList.Add(player); 
}
```

and later in this test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CheckTeamOfPlayer9()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(wcm.GetPlayerById(9).PlayerTeam.CountryName, "Japan");
}
```

I get the following error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` with the null reference exception.
This is the method the test runs:

```
public Player GetPlayerById(int playerId)
{
    var result = from b in Players
                 where b.PersonId.Equals(playerId)
                 select b;

    return result.FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```

Any one has an idea?

Comment: why do you create a new Team `t` in your first method?

Comment: Your debugger will tell you where the problem is. Some referenced object is null.

Comment: Where are you creating a player with ID 9? `GetPlayerById` will return null if there's no such player...

Comment: `wcm.GetPlayerById(9).PlayerTeam` is the culprit.  Either wcm, GetPlayerById(9) or PlayerTeam is returning null.

Comment: And what would you like us to do? Do you want us to guess which of the references contains a null reference? It's impossible for us to see and very easy for you to check, since you are running your program and having presumably using a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return result.FirstOrDefault()` will return a default value if thaere is no match. In the case of Player, that is null.

Check the result of `wcm.GetPlayerById(9)`. Presumably it is null.